# Почему происходит ошибка "EJB Timer Service is not available"?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Я создал `Stateless bean` который имеет метод, обозначенный аннотацией `@Schedule`. Запускаю я бин с помощью сервлета.
Код бина:

```
@Stateless
public class StockServerBean {
private String price=null;
private ArrayList<String> nasdaqSymbols = new ArrayList<String>();
private String chooseSymb;
public String getChooseSymb() {
    return chooseSymb;
}

public void setChooseSymb(String chooseSymb) {
    this.chooseSymb = chooseSymb;
}

public StockServerBean(){
    // Define some hard-coded NASDAQ symbols
    nasdaqSymbols.add("AAPL");
    nasdaqSymbols.add("MSFT");
    nasdaqSymbols.add("YHOO");
    nasdaqSymbols.add("AMZN");
    nasdaqSymbols.add("MOT");
}

@Schedule(second="*",minute="*",hour="18,00-22,00", dayOfWeek="Mon-Sun")
public void getQuote(){
    if(nasdaqSymbols.indexOf(chooseSymb.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
    // Generate a random price for valid symbols
    price = (new Double(Math.random()*100)).toString();
    }
    Session session = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    try{
        Context jndiC = new InitialContext();
        factory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiC.lookup("MyTestConnectionFactory");
        Queue queue = (Queue)jndiC.lookup("MyJMSTestQueue");
        
        conn = factory.createConnection();
        conn.start();
        
        session = conn.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        
        MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(queue); 
        TextMessage outM = session.createTextMessage(chooseSymb + " : " + price);
        sender.send(outM);
        sender.close();
        System.out.println("Succesfully placed a price of  "  + chooseSymb + " :"+ price);
        
    }catch(JMSException je){
        System.out.println("Error: " + je.getMessage());
    }catch(NamingException ne){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ne.getMessage());
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            session.close();
            conn.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Can't close session/connection :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Код сервлета:

```
@WebServlet("/ExecutionServlet")
public class ExecutionServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ExecutionServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StockServerBean bean = new StockServerBean();
    bean.setChooseSymb("AAPL");
    bean.getQuote();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Sending price to the queue");
    
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

В результате выдает ошибку:

```
cannot Deploy Lesson32
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while loading the app : EJB Timer Service is not available. 
Please see server.log for more details.
```

Полный код ошибки:

```
[2015-10-29T21:53:23.581+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026]            
[javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)]    [timeMillis: 1446148403581] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available
    at   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.startApplication(BaseContainer.java:4009)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Следуя [указаниям](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2434/ggrvi.html#glhn), я создал в `glassfish` свойство:

> com.sun.ejb.timer.ReadDBBeforeTimeout=false.

Но ошибка осталась та же.. Помогите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: Сам сервис таймеров сконфигурирован и запущен? Может поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786424/glassfish-scheduletimer-exception

Comment: а как именно нужно конфигурировать его?? в админ. консоле я нашел эти вкладки, но что нужно там изменять я вообще не представляю. Я так понял изменить нужно значение в server-config -> EJB Container -> EJB Timer Service tab в поле Timer Datasource. А в вкладке Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Connection Pools -> __TimerPool  я не понимаю при чем тут вообще jdbc, если у меня нету никаких баз данных....

Comment: Может ничего менять а настройках сервера не надо было? Таймер должен работать сразу же. А jdbc тут при том, что можно настроить как сервер будет хранить таймеры (они персистентные, но некоторым, если не всем, это можно отключить), если не устраивает метод по умолчанию. В том числе можно хранить и в базе данных. Вот тут и появляется jdbc.

Comment: Ну так сначала я ничего и не менял, и не работало, потом поменял лишь в server-config -> EJB Container -> EJB Timer Service tab в поле Timer Datasource ввел _TimerPool. И ничего...

Comment: Глянул в glassfish 3. Хотя там тоже ничего нет в Timer Datasource, но есть JDBC Connection Pool с названием __TimerPool. Два подчёркивания впереди. В 3 версии таймеры работали безо всяких телодвижений.

Comment: Попробуй вернуть настройки как они были до вмешательства. Там вроде даже кнопка есть. Остановить сервер. Найти базу таймеров domain1/lib/databases/ejbtimer и удалить её. Или для начала файлы с расширением lck (блокировки). Заглянуть в папки applications и generated. Там тоже всё поудалять, что связано с таймером. По названию будет сразу видно: ejb-timer-*. Перед удалением естественно всё копировать на всякий случай

Comment: Попробовал все... И ничего не помогло..

Comment: Если это связано с сохранением таймера, как написали в ответе на вопрос. То можно еще попробовать у @Schedule поставить persistent = false

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, таймеры работают на основе внутренней JAVADB, проверьте в панели управления :4848 пул JDBC/JDBC connection pool/__timerPool пингом, есть ли ответ. Удалите /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/databases/ejbtimer, и удалите файл-флаг ошибки /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/ejb-timer-service-app, перезапустите сервер, она должна восстановиться